# How to restrict anonymous users without ajax error risk?

Tags: 7, users, ajax

I want to restrict anonymous users from viewing the site accept few pages. There are few modules. I was using [require login](https://www.drupal.org/require_login) module. It was working perfectly as it redirected anonymous users to login page, but after some time past, I was getting an ajax error mentioned in my previous [question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/228833/not-able-to-login-getting-ajax-error). So I had to uninstall [require_login](https://www.drupal.org/require_login) module.

Is there any other way to have such functionality without having a risk of ajax errors?

The previous question was closed so here is the screen shot

[image]

Comment: Your previous question is inaccessible. I suppose the Ajax response was invalid because it was serving the login page rather than the ajax response, but could you edit the conclusion in the question?

Comment: @Neograph734 edited